# How can I limit items in ngFor repeat to some number in div and then repeat in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a image gallery and i want x number of image to be in a `<div>` and then repeat same `div` for next x number of image.
I tried various tricks after searching on google, but all failed.
I want to maintain CSS properties of all classes

My code is

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="myimages">
        <div class="first-column"  *ngFor="let item of projectList | keyvalue">
            <img [src]=' item.value.img' alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output is like

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="myimages">
        <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='1.img' alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='2.img' alt="image">
        </div>
       <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='3.img' alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='4.img' alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired output is

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="myimages">
        <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='1.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='2.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='3.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='4.img' alt="image">
        </div>
        
        <div class="first-column">
            <img [src]='5.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='6.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='7.img' alt="image">
            <img [src]='8.img' alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how it will sove the issue, i dont want exactly two rows, but i want x number of  rows depending on number of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `index` in combination with modulus operator in your loop:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="myimages">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of projectList | keyvalue" let-i="index">
            <div class="first-column" *ngIf="i % 4 === 0">
                <img [src]="projectList[i].value.img" alt="image">
                <img [src]="projectList[i + 1].value.img" alt="image">
                <img [src]="projectList[i + 2].value.img" alt="image">
                <img [src]="projectList[i + 3].value.img" alt="image">
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i have 100 images or 1000 images... do i need to write <div class="first-column"> number of times

Comment: I have edited my post. Didn't test, maybe needs minor adjustments but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: on this error i am getting is "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. , if i replare container by template then compiler is not executing code inside ng-template